# Ford Transit roof bag possibility

Tags: ford

I'm going on a family road trip and we're renting a Ford Transit van.  I've rented these before but in the past, fewer people went so there was more room in the cabin for stuff.  I was thinking about getting one of those roof bags that strap on the roof but it's not clear if any of those will strap on in a reliable manner since they seem to use door jams (or built in luggage racks which we won't have) but I'm not sure that works with sliding doors.

Could someone give me some insight as to whether or not the roof bag is viable for a Ford Transit?

Comment: Can you tell us what variant and year of Transit you're renting?

Comment: @motosubatsu Unfortunately I don't know for certain.  What I do know is that I'm renting from Enterprise, it is 15 passenger capable, and it is NOT the high roof version.  Other than that I'm just guessing.  Based on those facts, I'd assume it's the cheapest base 2019 model available that seats 15 people.

Comment: @motosubatsu After looking at more pictures I'm thinking I could run straps through the front doors and then through the back to the very rear door like a triangle.

Comment: To be honest (depending on how big a bag you are thinking of) you might be better off running both sets of straps through the front doors. Most bags happily function this way (it's how they work for 3/2 door cars). I'd advise getting a non-slip mat to put under it though or you'll scratch the heck out of the roof.